# what samples will buffer contain when I use installTap(onBus for multichannel audio?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

what samples will buffer contain when I use installTap(onBus for multichannel audio?

If channel count > 1 then it will contain left microphone ? or it will contain samples from left microphone and right microphone?

when I use iphone simulator  then  Format = pcmFormatFloat32, channelCount = 2, sampleRate = 44100.0, not Interleaved

I use this code

```
let bus = 0
inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: myTapOnBusBufferSize, format: theAudioFormat) {
            (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
            self.onNewBuffer(buffer)
        }

func onNewBuffer(_ inputBuffer:AVAudioPCMBuffer!)
{
    var samplesAsDoubles:[Double] = []

    for i in 0 ..< Int(inputBuffer.frameLength)
    {
        let theSample = Double((inputBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i])!)
        samplesAsDoubles.append( theSample )
    }
}

print("number of input busses = \(inputNode.numberOfInputs)")
```

it print 
number of input buses = 1

for each sample in my samplesAsDoubles  array from buffer that I have inside of block from what channel it will be? at what time this sample was recorded?

Comment: about reading multichannel buffer see lecture wwdc 2014
What's New in Core Audio in => 55min

Answer (score 3):

From the header comments for floatChannelData:

> The returned pointer is to format.channelCount pointers to float. Each of these pointers
>               is to "frameLength" valid samples, which are spaced by "stride" samples.
>
> If format.interleaved is false (as with the standard deinterleaved float format), then 
>               the pointers will be to separate chunks of memory. "stride" is 1.

FloatChannelData gives you a 2D float array.  For a non-interleaved 2 channel buffer, you would access the individual samples like this:

```
let channelCount = Int(buffer.format.channelCount)
let frameCount = Int(buffer.frameLength)

if let channels = buffer.floatChannelData {  //channels is 2D float array
    for channelIndex in 0..<channelCount {
        let channel = channels[channelIndex] //1D float array
        print(channelIndex == 0 ? "left" : "right")
        for frameIndex in 0..<frameCount {
            let sample = channel[frameIndex]
            print("    \(sample)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave
Thanks for answer.
Really helpful.
Now I see what I need . But what is stride for memory and what is 2D float array I do not understand

Comment: You should search stackoverflow to find answers for these other questions.  If you can't find the answers there, compose new questions :)